# Как назначить файл перевода ru_RU.po из дочерней темы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется тема, структура папок примерно такая:

```
wp-content/themes/themename/assets  
wp-content/themes/themename/inc  
wp-content/themes/themename/lang
wp-content/themes/themename/template
wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php
wp-content/themes/themename/page.php 
wp-content/themes/themename/single.php
```

Как можно переопределить файл языка `ru_RU.po` в дочерней теме?

Т.е. данный файл находится в папке `wp-content/themes/themename/lang/ru_RU.po`.
Есть ли хуки для этого, или нужно изучать основную тему и искать подключение 
 данного файла локализации и переопределить это подключение в дочерней теме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в `functions.php` вашей темы

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'themename', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lang' );
```

Файл `ru_RU.po` скопируйте в папку `/lang` дочерней темы, там скомпилируйте его в `.mo`.

Comment: Подскажите, допустим имеется две страницы лендинга на двух языках. По умолчанию включена англ-я версия, при переходе по ссылке в шапке, к примеру `sitename.com/ru`, открывается русская версия. Сейчас на двух версиях страниц загружается русский перевод. Как сделать, чтобы на нужной странице определялся нужный перевод?

Comment: Плагины мультиязычности: WPML, Polylang.

Comment: интересует именно решение без данных плагинов. Как можно поменять локаль на сайте, не в админке, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89965/108721